# DMA writing to allocated memory misses the first two adresses on the first write

Tags: c, arm, fpga, xilinx

I'm playing around with a ZYNQ7 (Dual-Core ARM) with a FPGA. The FPGA design has a 32-bit counter accessing the DDR via a DMA controller in chunks of 256-packets.

In the C-Code for the processor 1, I run a LWIP application to connect via ethernet to my pc.
There I allocate ram memory for the DMA transactions. The address of the pointer is passed via shared memory to the 2nd Core.

```
#define RCVADDR 0x1ef00002
u32_t * send=NULL;
u32_t* addr = (uint32_t*)RCVADDR;

//Allocating the memory once initially
if(send==NULL){
        send=malloc(256*sizeof(uint32_t));
    }

    *addr = (uint32_t)send;
    //starting the DMA on Core 2
    *getdma=1;
```

Using a handshake I initialize the DMA transactions in the second core and send the Data after finished transactions to the PC using a TCP connection on the 1st Core.

```
#define GetDMA  0x1ef00001
#define DONEDMA 0x1ef00003

uint8_t* getdma = (uint8_t*)GetDMA;
uint32_t* addr=(uint32_t*)RCVADDR;

    while(1){
        if(*getdma == 1){
            StartDMATransfer(*addr, 2048);  // The Number 2048 is the number Of Transfered Packets. It has to be at least the amount of Packets my Counter transfers in chunks. The design has a packet end indicator on its own. So 256 or bigger works the same as 256
            *getdma =0;

            Xil_DCacheFlush();

        }
    }
```

Before establishing a TCP-connection I flush the DCache

```
void send_data(){
    int ip_addr[4];
        u8_t i=0;

        char * token = strtok(ip,".");
        ip_addr[0] = atoi(token);

        while(token != NULL){

            ip_addr[++i]=atoi(strtok(NULL,"."));
        }
        Xil_DCacheFlushRange(send, 256*sizeof(uint32_t));

        //sleep(0.5);
        connect(ip_addr,atoi(port));
}
```

The Problem: The first Transmission Cycle after programming the Device shows:

[1280, 1281, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,.....
....., 248, 249,1530, 1531, 1532, 1533, 1534, 1535]

The first 2 Values and the last 6 values are from a previous Cycle before reprogramming the device.
However, this only occurs on the first DMA Transaction. Afterwards, while the device runs it never occurs once again.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution....

I had to flush the Cache after allocating the memory, before passing the address to the 2nd Core for processing.